# Excerpts and Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, excerpt

I have a declared a custom post type using the Types plugin.

When using a tag to display a page of these custom post types the excerpt shown is the full content of each post with formatting stripped.

When using a tag to display a page of normal posts the standard excerpt is displayed for each post.

I've corresponded with the plugin developers who tell me its the theme. The theme is using archive.php to display tag pages, I've looked at the theme code and it is simply using the_excerpt to display the posts.

Is the problem that the wp_trim_excerpt doesn't work on custom post types? Or is it some other filter that isn't being applied?

If I put a custom excerpt on a custom post type post it displays correctly.

Grateful for any help as going round in circles.

Comment: Search your theme files for `excerpt_length` - I reckon a dodgy filter is the cause.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what it was, the excerpt_length was being set in a number of places.